# How to show that $\log^n(n)=o(n!)$?

Tags: asymptotics

I am looking for a rigorous proof of $\log^n(n)=o(n!)$.

I was thinking of using this property: If $f(n), g(n) \geq 1 \ \forall\in \mathbb{N}$, and $\log f(n)=o(\log g(n)),$ then $f(n)=o(g(n)).$ However, $\log^n(n)=0$ for $n=1$, so I don't know what to do. Any help is appreciated. Note that all logs are base 2 since this problem is from a computer science class.

Comment: By $\log^n(n)$ do you mean $[\log(n)]^n$ or $\underbrace{\log\log\cdots\log(n)}_{n\text{ times}}$?

Comment: I mean $[\log(n)]^n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to avoid Stirling here.

Let us take the definition of $o(\cdot)$. For any "big" $c > 1$, there is an $N$ such that for all $n > N$, $c \log^n(n) \leq n!$. We also need to know that $(n/2)^{n/2} \leq n!$. (This is a simple fact and there are many proofs on MSE)

$$
c \log^n(n) \leq n! \Longleftarrow c\log^n(n) \leq (n/2)^{n/2}
$$
Taking $(\cdot)^{1/n}$ and rearranging gives
$$
c\log^n(n) \leq (n/2)^{n/2} \Longleftrightarrow (c)^{1/n} \sqrt{2} \leq \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\log(n)}
$$
Now clearly the RHS is increasing toward $\infty$ while the LHS is decreasing toward $\sqrt{2}$ (a bit of calculus and L'Hopital can show it), and this whatever $c$ may be. Hence this inequality must be true at some point which gives us an $N$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\log^n(n)< cn!$ instead of $c\log^n(n)\le n!$?

Comment: Well in my post, I assume $c$ to be "big". The goal is to show that however we try to make the LHS large with a multiplicative constant, the RHS will always eventually win. Putting a "big" $c$ on the RHS can only make thing easier to prove. But in the end, it's equivalent if we simply rename $c$ to be $c'=1/c$ and divide on both sides.

Answer (score 1):

By [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation),
$$
n!\sim\sqrt{2\pi n}\Bigl(\frac{n}e\Bigr)^n\quad\text{as}\quad n\to\infty,
$$
where $\sim$ means that the ratio tends to $1$. Hence,
$$
\frac{\log^nn}{n!}=\frac{\sqrt{2\pi n}(n/e)^n}{n!}\cdot\frac{\log^n n}{\sqrt{2\pi n}(n/e)^n}.
$$
Since
$$
\frac{\log n}{n}\to 0\quad\text{as}\quad n\to\infty
$$
(see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1671565/23249)), we have that $(\log n)/n<1/e$ for sufficiently large $n$. Hence, for sufficiently large $n$,
$$
\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi n}}\biggl(\frac{e\log n}{n}\biggr)^n\le\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi n}}
$$
and the right hand side goes to $0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: What techniques/theorems might a proof that doesn't use Stirling's approximation use?

Comment: @user126605 I suspect there should be more elegant ways to show this, but this is the only proof that I can come up with at the moment.